# How to use a Java library like AChartEngine with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, charts

I am developing an Android app which requires to displays various types of charts. A quick research reveled that [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/index.html) would be the perfect fit.

Unfortunately, the project is kind of outdated. The referenced repositories for [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) IDE are not existing anymore, and the few linked and still available tutorials also referring to the non-existing repositories.

[The "new" Github repository](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine) does not have releases. So I guess, I cannot use with with Gradle dependencies as version numbers are required.

How to use (include/import) AChartEngine in a 2018's Android Studio (v3.2.1; with Gradle) setup?

I would like to achieve the following sample code (taken and modified from [survivingwithandroid.com](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/06/android-chart-tutorial-achartengine.html)):

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Foo Bar Chart");
Random rn = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  series.add(i, (int)rn.nextInt(10+i) + 1;);
}
XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
renderer.setLineWidth(2);
renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
renderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
renderer.setPointStrokeWidth(3);
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00)); 
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
mRenderer.setYAxisMax(35);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataset, mRenderer);
chartLinearLayout.addView(chartView, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a maven project:

```
git clone https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine.git
cd achartengine/achartengine
mvn package
```

which results in:

```
./target/achartengine-1.2.0.jar
```

Comment: Sometimes, I want to break the wall, I just smashed my head in... Thank you.

Comment: Why in achartengine 1.2.0 the dataset or ChartFactory does not exit.I am using implementation "org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0" with android studio 3.6.3